# How to use ttf fonts in a Facebook php app [heroku] via imagettftext

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I use the following code to use imagettftext() function on a png image.

But it does not seem to work.

Any solutions?

The ttf font is in the current directory of the index.php file

```
<?php 
        require ("sdk/src/facebook.php");
        $facebook=new Facebook(array('appId'=>'144694832322411','secret'=>'56456456456e6f75a5c4657befa','fileUpload'=>true,));

        $user = $facebook->getUser();

        if($user){
                 echo "User";
                 $im = imagecreate(200,200);
                 $rt='font.ttf';
                 $col = imagecolorallocate($im,255,0,0);
                 $v= imagecolorallocate($im,255,0,0);
                 try{
                imagettftext($im,30.0,0.0,0,0,$v,$rt,"Hello");} catch (Exception $e){print_r($e);}
                 imagepng($im,'img.png');
                 echo "<img src='img.png'></img>";
             } else {
                      $auth= "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=144694832322411&redirect_uri=".urlencode("https://apps.facebook.com/lucky_elements")."&scope=user_about_me";
                       echo "<script>top.location.href=\"$auth\"</script>";
                      }


        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

heroku doesn't support imagettftext(), it doesn't support pfb fonts, and it has buggy gdf support, which doesn't look to work properly.
so either change server, or try building custom builds ( https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php )